# Splitting a text by a delimiter in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to split the input from **eventIDs** by a delimiter like **','**.

In example the Input in this stored procedure is **('852', '159,11031', '5')**.

So I want to call the stored procedure **sp_case_attach_event** two times.

One time with **('852', '159', '5')** and one time with **('852', '11031', '5')**

The following code is written by another person, who isn't available. But the code isn't working, because it throws an error:

> SQL Fehler (1292): Truncated incorrect INTEGER value:','

I can't figure out where the issue is.

```
[...]

PROCEDURE `sp_case_attach_event_list`(IN `caseID` INT, IN `eventIDs` text, IN `userID` INT)

[...]    
BEGIN
    DECLARE inipos INTEGER;
    DECLARE endpos INTEGER;
    DECLARE maxlen INTEGER;
    DECLARE item VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE delim VARCHAR(1);

    SET delim = ',';
    SET inipos = 1;
    SET eventIDs = CONCAT(eventIDs, delim);
    SET maxlen = LENGTH(eventIDs);

    REPEAT
        SET endpos = LOCATE(delim, eventIDs, inipos);
        SET item =  SUBSTR(eventIDs, inipos, endpos - inipos);

        IF item <> '' AND item IS NOT NULL THEN           
            call sp_case_attach_event(caseID,eventIDs,userID);
        END IF;
        SET inipos = endpos + 1;
    UNTIL inipos >= maxlen END REPEAT;
    END
```

The code of the second stored procedure. It does work with the example data **('852', '159', '5')** and **('852', '11031', '5')**:

**sp_case_attach_event**

```
[..]
PROCEDURE `sp_case_attach_event`(IN `caseID` INT, IN `eventID` INT, IN `userID` INT)
[..]
BEGIN

DECLARE modificationID INT;

select count(ontbl_analyse_event.modification_ID) into @countENTRY from ontbl_analyse_event where ontbl_analyse_event.analyse_ID = caseID and ontbl_analyse_event.event_ID = eventID;

if (@countENTRY = 0) then 
        insert into ontbl_modification (ontbl_modification.creator_ID,ontbl_modification.date) values (userID,now());
    SET modificationID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        insert into ontbl_analyse_modification (ontbl_analyse_modification.analyse_ID,ontbl_analyse_modification.modification_ID,ontbl_analyse_modification.textlog_description)  values (caseID,modificationID,'event attached');

        insert into ontbl_analyse_event (ontbl_analyse_event.analyse_ID, ontbl_analyse_event.event_ID, ontbl_analyse_event.modification_ID) values (caseID, eventID, modificationID);
end if;
END
```

Comment: Please tag the database that you are using

Comment: Please do share with us the code of the second procedure you are colling from inside of this procedure: `sp_case_attach_event`. Because as you can see here there is nothing wrong when I call this procedure without calling the other procedure: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9ac188e960e5736b2e04f810b10fb11

Comment: I don't see any `SET eventIDs =` except outside the loop. Did you mean `call sp_case_attach_event(caseID, **item**,userID);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a little problem here:

```
call sp_case_attach_event(caseID,eventIDs,userID);
```

You're not modifying the `eventIDs` variable inside the loop but the `item` variable. So I guess it should be:

```
call sp_case_attach_event(caseID,item,userID);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the issue and now it's working.